# how can i show input value under another input value like facebook comment?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

how can I create another comment in the printed value like as facebook comment.I want when the value will display after submitting under that value reply option will be show and when i click on reply the another input box will show, so that I would comment again on that printed value as like facebook. And I want the input value will clear after submitting.

can any one help me find this problem?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn").click(function(){
    let getVal = $("#inputValue").val();
    let img = `<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1503023345310-bd7c1de61c7d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80" class="rounded-circle" height="30px" width="30px">`
    $("#output").html($("#output").html() + " " + img + getVal + `<br>` );
  });
});
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div id="main">
  <div id="output"></div>    
    <input id="inputValue" type="text" name="text">
  <button id="btn" class="btn btn-primary">display value</button>
</div>
```

Comment: If you want to clear the input use `$("#inputValue").val("")`, if you want to be able to reply to previous comments, then I surggest you structure your html/code different. perhaps use `ul/li`

Comment: Can you show me a small example please...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var replyHtml = "<br><input type='button' class='reply' value='reply'><div style='display:none;'><input type='text' placeholder='reply'><input type='button' class='rep-submit' value='reply'></div>";
  
  $("#btn").click(function(){
    let getVal = $("#inputValue").val() + replyHtml;
    let img = `<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1503023345310-bd7c1de61c7d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80" class="rounded-circle" height="30px" width="30px">`
    $("#output").html($("#output").html() + " " + img + getVal + `<br>` );
    $("#inputValue").val('')
  });
  
  $(document).on('click', '.reply', function(){
    $(this).next().show();
    $(this).remove();
  });
  
  $(document).on('click', '.rep-submit', function(){
    var reply = $(this).prev().val();
    $(this).closest('div').html(reply + replyHtml);
  });
});
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div id="main">
  <div id="output"></div>    
    <input id="inputValue" type="text" name="text">
  <button id="btn" class="btn btn-primary">display value</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with something like this-

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn").click(function(){
    let getVal = $("#inputValue").val();
    let img = `<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1503023345310-bd7c1de61c7d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80" class="rounded-circle" height="30px" width="30px">`
    let replyInput = '<div class="ml-5"><input type="text" id="replyText">&nbsp;&nbsp;<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="reply">reply</button></div>'
    $("#output").html($("#output").html() + " " + img + getVal + `<br>`+ replyInput );
  });
});
```

```html
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div id="main">
  <div class="m-5" id="output"></div>    
    <input id="inputValue" type="text" name="text">
  <button id="btn" class="btn btn-primary">display value</button>
</div>
```

Comment: no not like that the value of reply will also print

Comment: is this possible to do that?

Comment: yes it is possible, just need to map each reply input box and button with it's parent comment dynamically.

You've answer in the above code. just implement it using DOM manipulation.